# Losses in DC generator

Tags: dc-motor

[image]

While working through the question ,I calculated the field copper losses and field armature losses which came to be 1250 watts and 271 watts respectively so total loses should be 1521 watts but they have given it to be 2771 watts.I didn't get why they added the extra 1250 watts that we get from No load condition from the DC motor case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1250 W no load motor losses are those losses that occur when the machine is turning. The largest of these is 'windage', the viscosity and turbulence of the air surrounding the rotor. There are also bearing friction and core eddy current losses.

These will all be the same when the machine is turning, if the speed and the flux are the same, whether it's running as a motor or generator. The 1250 W loss therefore has to be added to the copper losses.

Comment: Doesn't the 1250 W contain just the copper loss?

Comment: It's a pity the author chose an example where the loss comprised two equal terms, so it was not apparent which was which. You'll agree that both motoring mode and generating mode mean a machine that's turning, so suffers from having to stir the air around in the casing. This mechnaical speed dependent loss is the difference between the motor input power of 2500 W, and the computed electrical losses of 1250 W, leaving the mech losses as 1250 W.

Comment: One last thing.From some searching, it says field copper loss is also a constant loss so shouldn't the constant losses be just difference of power of motor and armature cu loss since it's the only thing variable

Comment: Field copper loss is a function of the field excitation, so if that's thje same, the loss is the same. In a shunt machine, field excitation depends on terminal voltage. When mechanical power is equal, terminal voltage will be different (higher in motor due to IR losses), so be careful to check which things are identical, and which just similar.